# How to change dbo ownership to another user login in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The existing Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 was moved to another domain. The existing dbo owner belongs to the old domain.

I need to change the dbo ownership to a new login user, not to a 'sa'. I have seen some sample codes but I am not sure the correct syntax for the new user name.

I have already tried changing the ownership using within SQL Server Management Studio, properties of the database and changing the value from the files but it did work.

For instance, I see someone suggesting:

```
-- in master db
CREATE LOGIN [login1] WITH PASSWORD = '{Some Password}'
CREATE USER **[login1]** FOR LOGIN **[login1]**

-- in user db
CREATE USER **[login1]** FOR LOGIN **[login1]**
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER **[login1]**
```

the question I have is the `[login1]` format.

Usually, the login is: `domain\username`

How do I replace the `[login1]` with the actual login name? What is the correct format?

Besides changing the dbo ownership, I would like to know if there is anything else that needs to be done, as standard procedures, when the server where the SQL database is installed, has changed to a different domain.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The T-SQL statement `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO Login1;` will change the database owner per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql).

The login or database name need only be enclosed when it doesn't conform to [regular identifier naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) (like Windows logins with the backslash). So for a domain user, they syntax with square brackets is:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO [YourDomain\Login1];
```

or alternatively double quotes:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO "YourDomain\Login1";
```

I suggest you avoid using a domain user as the database owner going forward. This way, you won't have the problem when the computer domain changes or if the owning domain account becomes invalid for some reason, such as the individual leaves the organization.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thank you for your response. The "login1" that I want to add is a login user (domain user). Which is the correct syntax to type in for the "login1"? is it "domain\username"? It is, it did not work. I got an error saying the "\" was an invalid character.  I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: @user3757582 Have you tried `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO [domain\username];`, i.e. enclosing the domain account in rectangular brackets.

Comment: @user3757582, as a mentioned, the login name must be enclosed in the case of a domain user since it doesn't conform to the SQL Server rules for regular identifiers. I updated my answer to clarify.